Acceleration and Gyroscope read 0 on the ICM 20468
I'm trying to read from the ICM 20948 using a Pico W, however, whenever I read from the acceleration and gyroscope addresses I get 0. What could be the problem?
imu.c
void init_imu(IMU* imu) {
    gpio_set_function(imu->miso, GPIO_FUNC_SPI);
    gpio_set_function(imu->mosi, GPIO_FUNC_SPI);
    gpio_set_function(imu->clk, GPIO_FUNC_SPI);

    gpio_init(imu->cs);
    gpio_set_dir(imu->cs, GPIO_OUT);
    gpio_put(imu->cs, 1);


    uint8_t temp_data;

    enable_imu(imu);
    
    // Reset IMU
    write_reg(imu, PWR_MGMT_1, 0xc1, b0);
    sleep_ms(100);

    // Wake up from sleep
    write_reg(imu, PWR_MGMT_1, 0x01, b0);

    // output data rate start time alignment
    write_reg(imu, ODR_ALIGN_EN, 0x01, b2);

    // gyroscope config sample rate divisor
    write_reg(imu, GYRO_SMPLRT_DIV, 0x00, b2);

    // gyroscope range and disable filtering
    write_reg(imu, GYRO_CONFIG_1, GYRO_RANGE << 1, b2);

    // acclerometer sample rate diivider
    write_reg(imu, ACCEL_SMPLRT_DIV_1, 0x00, b2);
    write_reg(imu, ACCEL_SMPLRT_DIV_2, 0x00, b2);

    // Accelerometer configuration, sample rate divider = 0 and disabled filtering
    write_reg(imu, ACCEL_CONFIG, ACCEL_RANGE << 1, b2);

    // Set to SPI mode only
    read_reg(imu, USER_CTRL, b0, &temp_data, 1);
    temp_data |= 0x10;
    write_reg(imu, USER_CTRL, temp_data, b2);

    select_bank(imu, b0);

    disable_imu(imu);
}

void get_data(IMU* imu, Sample* smp) {
    uint8_t data_rx[12];
    uint8_t temp_data = READ_BIT | ACCEL_XOUT_H;

    enable_imu(imu);
    read_reg(imu, temp_data, b0, data_rx, 12);

    smp->accel_x = (((int16_t) data_rx[0] << 8)) + data_rx[1];
    smp->accel_y = (((int16_t) data_rx[2] << 8)) + data_rx[3];
    smp->accel_z = (((int16_t) data_rx[4] << 8)) + data_rx[5];

    smp->gyro_x = (((int16_t) data_rx[6] << 8)) + data_rx[7];
    smp->gyro_y = (((int16_t) data_rx[8] << 8)) + data_rx[9];
    smp->gyro_z = (((int16_t) data_rx[10] << 8)) + data_rx[11];

    disable_imu(imu);
}

void wait() {
    sleep_us(500);
}

void enable_imu(IMU* imu) {
    gpio_put(imu->cs, 0);
    wait();
}

void disable_imu(IMU* imu) {
    gpio_put(imu->cs, 1);
    wait();
}

void write_reg(IMU* imu, uint8_t reg, uint8_t value, user_bank usr_bnk) {
    select_bank(imu, usr_bnk);

    uint8_t data[2];

    data[0] = reg;
    data[1] = value;

    spi_write_blocking(SPI_PORT, data, 2);

    wait();
}

void read_reg(IMU* imu, uint8_t reg, user_bank usr_bnk, uint8_t* buffer, uint buffer_size) {
    select_bank(imu, usr_bnk);

    uint8_t send_read_bit = reg | READ_BIT;

    spi_write_blocking(SPI_PORT, &send_read_bit, 1);
    wait();
    spi_read_blocking(SPI_PORT, 0, buffer, buffer_size);
}

void select_bank(IMU* imu, user_bank usr_bnk) {
    uint8_t data[2];

    data[0] = BANK_SEL_REGISTER;
    data[1] = (uint8_t) usr_bnk;

    spi_write_blocking(SPI_PORT, data, 2);
    wait();
}

main.c
int main()
{
    stdio_init_all();
    spi_init(SPI_PORT, FREQ);

    IMU yellow_imu = {
        .miso = YELLOW_MISO,
        .mosi = YELLOW_MOSI,
        .clk  = YELLOW_SCLK,
        .cs   = YELLOW_CS
    };

    IMU green_imu = {
        .miso = GREEN_MISO,
        .mosi = GREEN_MOSI,
        .clk  = GREEN_SCLK,
        .cs   = GREEN_CS
    };

    IMU red_imu = {
        .miso = RED_MISO,
        .mosi = RED_MOSI,
        .clk  = RED_SCLK,
        .cs   = RED_CS
    };


    Sample curr_smp;
    init_imu(&yellow_imu);
    init_imu(&green_imu);
    init_imu(&red_imu);

    while(1){
        get_data(&yellow_imu, &curr_smp);

        printf("\nAcceleration x: %.4f", curr_smp.accel_x);

        sleep_ms(100);
    }
}

